# Pronunciation of -ai(s) verbal endings / Prononciation des terminaisons en -ai(s)

Tags: prononciation, temps-grammatical, conjugaison, mode-grammatical, accents-régionaux

When speaking in the first person (*je*), is there a difference when pronouncing a verb conjugated in the *futur* and *passé simple* (*-ai*) and in the *conditional* and *imparfait* (*-ais*)? For instance, is there a difference between those two:

- *Je serai*
- *Je serais*

---

Y a-t-il une différence de prononciation entre les terminaisons *-ai* du futur et du passé simple et *-ais* du conditionnel et de l'imparfait ? Par exemple, y a-t-il une différence ici :

- *Je serai*
- *Je serais*

Comment: I started a bounty because I'd welcome a more sourced answer, in particular include links to (or copies of) audio recordings exhibiting the possible pronunciation differences *for a given speaker* (let's say, snippets of someone well-known saying the same verb with the two variants).

Comment: Agreed, the currently accepted answer was far too insufficient; and good idea to ask for sound references which will be a definitive plus point.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is a difference.

The "-ai" ending is a [close-mid front unrounded vowel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close-mid_front_unrounded_vowel) (`[e]`) which is similar to the North American way of saying "play" (but please bear in mind that comparing sounds from one language to another isn't very wise). In French, you'll find the same sound represented by an "é" (e acute). For example, both "[grimpai](http://www.cnrtl.fr/morphologie/grimpai)" and "[grimpé](http://www.cnrtl.fr/morphologie/grimp%C3%A9)" are listed as having the same pronunciation.

For an audio example, [listen](http://www.tv5.org/TV5Site/dictee/dictee.php) to the "[dictée de Pivot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernard_Pivot)" titled "Beyrouth 2004", the fifth sequence (Select "Senior", then "Séquence 5" in the dropdown) starts with "Je les leur infligeai".

The "-ais" ending is an [open-mid front unrounded vowel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-mid_front_unrounded_vowel) (`[ɛ]` in API, but [ATILF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/morphologie/grimpais) uses the [SAMPA Symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_Assessment_Methods_Phonetic_Alphabet_chart) `E`) such as the one you'd use in "bed" (same caveat applies). In French, you'll also find the same sound represented by an "è" or an "ê".

For an audio example, listen to the fourth sequence of the same dictation. These are not conjugated verbs, but the way "Français" and "Libanais" are pronounced is the same.

Also, note that apparently some people pronounce the "-ai" ending the same way as the "-ais" one, which may be region-dependant. There seems to be no doubt on the "-ais" ending, which is why the dictation example should be good enough.

---

Il y a une [différence](http://dardel.info/Prononciation.html).

La terminaison « -ai » est une [voyelle mi-fermée antérieure non arrondie](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyelle_mi-ferm%C3%A9e_ant%C3%A9rieure_non_arrondie) (`[e]`) qui est la même que celle représentée par un « é » (e accent aigu). Les conjugaisons « [grimpai](http://www.cnrtl.fr/morphologie/grimpai) » et « [grimpé](http://www.cnrtl.fr/morphologie/grimp%C3%A9) » ont la même prononciation.

Pour un exemple auditif, [écouter](http://www.tv5.org/TV5Site/dictee/dictee.php) la [dictée de Pivot](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dict%C3%A9e_de_Pivot) « Beyrouth 2004 », la cinquième séquence (dans la version pour séniors) commence par « Je les leur infligeai ».

La terminaison « -ais » est une [voyelle mi-ouverte antérieure non arrondie](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyelle_mi-ouverte_ant%C3%A9rieure_non_arrondie)
 (API `[ɛ]`, l'[ATILF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/morphologie/grimpais) utilise le [symbole SAMPA](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symboles_SAMPA) `E`) et se prononce comme un « è » (e accent grave).

Pour un exemple auditif, écouter la séquence 4 de la dictée précitée. Bien qu'il ne s'agisse pas d'une conjugaison, la terminaison de « Français » et « Libanais » est la même.

De plus, il semble que certaines personnes prononcent la terminaison « -ai » de la même manière que la terminaison « -ais », peut-être suivant les régions. La terminaison « -ais » suscite moins de doute, ce qui fait que l'exemple de la dictée devrait suffire.

Comment: C'est intéressant. En France métropolitaine, je ne fais vraiment aucune différence entre les deux...

Comment: @Raphink: je me demande si il n'y a pas une autre raison derrière ça. Quand utilisons-nous réellement le passé simple?

Comment: Pouvez-vous donner une référence où cette différence serait décrite ?

Comment: @Joubarc le passé simple, pas trop, mais je futur de l'indicatif, beaucoup plus...

Answer (score 6):

De façon plus ou moins normalisée, les terminaisons en *–ai* sont, comme celles en *–er* ou *–ez*, censées être prononcées « *é* » `[e]`. Celles en *–ais* sont censées être prononcées « *è* » `[ɛ]`.

En pratique (je réponds en tant que Français, région Midi-Pyrénées et Paris notamment) je ne rencontre pas couramment de différence de prononciation. Dans « Je grimper**ai** à l'arbre. » (futur) et « S'il le fallait, je grimper**ais** à l'arbre. » (conditionnel), les deux verbes se prononcent souvent de la même manière. Un intermédiaire entre « *è* » et « *é* » : une antérieure moyenne non arrondie ; le `e̞` que l'on trouve dans [le tableau des voyelles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPA_vowel_chart_with_audio). Dans le sud on aurait tendance à nommer ce son « *é* » alors qu'à Paris il serait plus proche d'un « è ».  Dans d'autres régions — Belgique et d'autres que je ne saurais nommer — la différence de prononciation est plus clairement marquée.

À noter : « grimpai » (passé simple) et « grimpais » (imparfait) ont respectivement mêmes son finaux que les précédents — souvent confondus selon mon expérience.

Comment: Apparement la réponse est peut-être différente suivant les régions. En Belgique en tous cas, il y a une différence claire entre les deux. Pas au Québec?

Comment: @Joubarc Je ne fais pas la différence (France, essentiellement Normandie et Paris). Je sais qu'il y a des gens qui la font, mais je n'ai jamais su qui au juste.

Comment: @Tipx, voir [ici](http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/questions/37/est-ce-quon-se-tutoie)

Comment: Stéphane, est-ce que vous prononcez _grimperai_ et _grimperez_ de la même façon ?

Comment: @dangph: Les terminaisons *–ez* et *–er* sont prononcées « *é* » par tout le monde. Les *–ai* sont censées être prononcées « *é* », et les *–ais* sont censées être prononcées « *è* ». En pratique j'entends rarement une différence marquée entre toutes ces prononciations.

Answer (score 5):

En Français¹, dans presque tous les cas, [e] et [ε] sont des variantes libre d'un même phonème, les seules exception étant à la finale. Donc de toute façon, la compréhension n'est en général pas un problème : quelle que soit la prononciation de *ai*, le contexte de la phrase permettra de comprendre l'intention².

En ce qui me concerne, je prononce les deux avec un [ε] (ou *e ouvert*, qui est la dernière voyelle de [*marais*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/marais#Prononciation)) et la prononciation [e] (ou *e fermé*, qui est la dernière voyelle de [*marée*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/mar%C3%A9e#Prononciation)) m'évoque soit la région parisienne soit le sud de la France³.

Pour des analogies en anglais,

> /e/ is pronounced like the last vowel of *crême brulée* or the *e* of *bed* in Australian English
>
> /ɛ/ is pronounced like the *e* of *bed* in British and American English

---

1. en tout cas dans la plupart de ses variantes.
2. ceci ne s'applique pas aux finales en *é*, *er*, *ez* qui sont systématiquement  prononcées [e]. Mais si le [ε] y paraitrait incorrect, il serait certainement compris. Si je devais faire des hypothèses fumeuses, je dirais que le français tend à considérer [e] comme la variante positionnelle du quasi-phonème /ε/e/ à la finale et que les *ai* qui seraient partout ailleurs prononcés [ε] sont en voie de disparition dans cette position. Le lecteur désireux d'en savoir plus pourra se reporter à cet excellent papier : [l'opposition [e]-[ε] en syllabe ouverte en fin de mot en français parisien](http://www.afcp-parole.org/doc/Archives_JEP/2002_XXIVe_JEP_Nancy/JEP2002/papiers/95.pdf).
3. Ou une chanson

   > *Un autre à la mamelle, on dit que j'en mourrai
   >
   >   Le beau prince d'Orange est mort et enterré
   >
   >   Que maudit soit la guerre, est mort et enterré*

Answer (score 4):

Les différentes prononciations de -ai, -ais, ai-, -ai- ... sont beaucoup plus de l'ordre de l'accent que de la graphie.

Par exemple à Toulouse la plupart de ces sons sont fermés alors qu'ils sont ouverts dans le Gers.

Comment: Je rajouterais également la région Lilloise où la prononciation de certains *ai/ais* à tendance à surprendre.

Answer (score 3):

Oui, il y a une différence de prononciation.
La prononciation du « ai » est plus courte que le « ais » — genre « é » tandis que la prononciation du « ais » est plus longue — genre « è ».

Comment: Attention, il y a des gens qui font une différence, et d'autres qui n'en font pas. Pour moi, par exemple, c'est toujours « è », au passé simple comme au futur comme à l'imparfait.

Answer (score 2):

*Rem. : Je prononce tout à la française (avec une pointe de belge), pas à la québécoise.*

« Je serai » est effectivement prononcé avec un accent fermé, comme « vous serez », « des », les terminaison de verbe en « -er ». mais je n’ai pas d’exemple anglais (Wikipedia suggère « play » prononcé à l’indienne).

« Je serais » se prononce avec un accent ouvert, comme « être », « connaître », « fête », ou l’anglais « get », « let », et tant d’autres.

Dans « Québec », « Qué- » est un accent fermé, « bec » un accent ouvert.

Remarquons que les accents (au sens de particularités locales de prononciation) influencent beaucoup la prononciation des accents (sur les e) et que, en particulier dans le cas de *serai/serais*, la différence tend à disparaître. Je pense que je prononce « serai » avec l’accent ouvert de « serais » dès que je ne fais pas attention.

Answer (score 1):

En France dans la pratique, la plupart des gens prononce les deux mots de la même manière : avec un « *è* ouvert » comme pour le mot *près*.

Ensuite, c'est le contexte de la phrase qui permet de savoir quel temps est employé.