# Prononciation de « il faisait »

Tags: prononciation

Comment se fait-il, que dans « il faisait » (le verbe faire à l'imparfait) le premier « ai » ne se prononce pas vraiment « ai » comme dans « il fait », mais plutôt « e » ? On prononce pourtant bien « ai » les deux « ai » dans « il se taisait » ?

Le même phénomène (?) se produit avec la prononciation du mot « [faisan](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faisan) » et du participe présent « en faisant ».

Comment: Je dirais même que ce premier "ai" se prononce comme "e" (`fesait`). Question que j'avais posé à ma mère, prof. de français et pour laquelle je n'ai toujours pas de réponse...

Comment: @AlexisWilke c'est vrai, « eu » est peut-être un peu trop prononcé. Je vais corriger ça.

Comment: La réponse à la question dans le titre se trouve ici: http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/95/pronunciation-of-ais-verbal-endings-prononciation-des-terminaisons-en-ais, mais elle ne traite pas du cas de *ai* en milieu de mot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gilles Ménage, dans ses [*Observations sur la langue française*](http://books.google.fr/books?id=UnRJjbQGTFEC&pg=PA292&lpg=PA292&dq=prononciation+%22faisant%22&source=bl&ots=z_-D3-28AE&sig=SMfsI42vSG2YuFAU8dMfoGFwTUg&hl=en&sa=X&ei=8du9UtXlI4a10QXT0ID4CQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=prononciation%20%22faisant%22&f=false) de 1672, écrit ceci :

> #### CLXVII. S'il faut dire *fesant*, ou *faisant*, au participe du verbe *faire*.
>
> Les Parisiens disent *fesant* au participe du verbe *faire* : ce qui a esté remarqué et blamé par Béze, en son livre de la prononciation de la Langue Françoise. *Neque hic mihi dissimulandum videtur vulgi Parisiensium vitium, qui *faisant* participium, pronunciant *fesant*, spondeo in jambum mutato*¹ La prononciation des Parisiens a prévalu. Il faut donc dire *fesant*, comme on dit *je ferois*, et *je feray*.

[Littré](http://www.littre.org/definition/faire) cite lui aussi Bèze et considère la prononciation en [fəz-] de *faisant*, *faisons*, *faisez*, *faisait*, etc. comme acquise.

Les autres mots de la famille de *faire* dont qui commencent par `fais-` (*faisable*, *faiseur*, etc.) se prononcent eux aussi [fəz-].

Je n'ai pas trouvé d'explication à cette faute des Parisiens. Il pourrait s'agir d'une contamination par la racine du futur (*ferai*, etc.). Le verbe latin *facio* était régulier aux temps actifs, mais la racine `fer-` remonte au moins à l'ancien français (« Nus les espees feruns vermeilles de chald sanc », dans la *Chanson de Roland*, cité par le [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/faire)). L'irrégularité du verbe en Latin (au passif), et l'existence des verbes *[ferio](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/ferio#Latin)* (frapper, qui a donné *férir*) et *[fero](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/fero#Latin)* (porter), combinées à la fréquence de son utilisation, ont pu contribuer à rendre ce verbe plus irrégulier.

Pour ce qui est du faisan, [Littré](http://www.littre.org/definition/faisan) affirme que la prononciation [fezɑ̃] (qui est aujourd'hui la seule) est minoritaire et due à une assimilation de *faisant*. Les deux racines sont effectivement les seules à avoir produit des mots commençant par `fais-` suivi d'une voyelle.

¹  <sub>Je m'essaie à traduire : et à ce sujet j'ai pu constater que le peuple parisien commet une faute, en prononçant *fesant* le participe *faisant*, et je m'engage à changer ??.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Comme tu le sais en français, certains graphes ont plusieurs prononciations (le o dans population et porte par exemple. "Faisait" n'est pas une exception car, en fait, "ai" peut bel et bien se prononcer de deux façons :

- /e/ en fin de mot comme dans : « gai » /ɡe/, « (je) mangeai » /mɑ̃ʒe/ mais certains locuteurs prononcent /ɛ/ comme dans « vrai » /vʁɛ/, « chai » /ʃɛ/, « balai » /balɛ/ etc. ou encore dans « sais », « vais », « sait » et « vait », où /ɛ/ est courant1,2,3,4.
- /ə/ par tout le monde dans certains cas : « faisan » /fəzɑ̃/, « faisant » /fəzɑ̃/, « faisons » /fəzɔ̃/, « faiseur » /fəzœʁ/, « faisable » /fəzabl/. Tu remarqueras avec faisan, que cela ne vient pas de l'étymologie du verbe faire

*Je pense, et cela n'engage que moi, que c'est lié au son /z/ qui suivrait le son /e/ assez difficile à prononcer.*

**Références :**

- http://www.ipasource.com/extras/diction/French%20Charts.pdf
- http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prononciation_du_fran%C3%A7ais#cite_note-ipasource-13

Comment: Je ne suis pas entièrement convaincu par ta remarque finale (celle qui *n'engage que toi*.) On n'a pas de mal à faire succéder ces sonorités quand elles sont en fin de mot, par exemple les adjectifs qui finissent par « ais » au féminin et dans certains noms : la charolaise est un exemple de vache française. Mais il est vrai que je ne trouve aucun exemple où ce son n'est pas à la fin du mot.

Comment: Oui, tout à fait, c'est pour les mêmes doutes que toi que j'ai notée cette remarque en italique et avec autant de «précautions». En y réfléchissant, on pourrait donner des contre-exemples du son /ez/ : Vésuve. Mais je ne trouve aucun mot avec le son "féz" /fez/ .

Comment: @Olivier D'accord avec toi. Pour l'exemple qui te manquait, il y a l'adjectif *plaisant* qui me semble échapper à la règle ayant transformé *faisan* et *faisant*.

Comment: @Alexandre T. Pardon d'avance pour ce demi hors-sujet mais... quelle différence entends-tu entre les *o* de *porc* et *porte* ? J'avoue n'en entendre aucune.

Comment: @Romain : Honte à moi ! Mon horrible accent lorrain m'aurait-il jouer un tour ? J'aurais dû dire "population" et "porte"...

Comment: @Alexandre Hehe, entre lorrains on devrait pourtant se comprendre ;-) Mais il faudrait préciser entre Moselle et Meurthe-et-Moselle, dont les accents sont assez différents (j'ai vécu environ 20 ans de chaque côté). A Nancy, les *o* sont presque tous prononcés comme celui de *porte*, même pour des mots comme *manteau*, *sirop* ou *landau*, ce qui est parfois assez étrange pour les non-nancéens en visite. (De même avec les *é* presque tous prononcés *è*)