# Why is "faisait" pronounced /fə.zɛ/?

Tags: prononciation

Considering the fact that just about every pronunciation guide says that "-ai" should be pronounced like "é" and "-ais" or "-ait" should be "è", I find the ə strange. What's the deal here?

Comment: Y a-t-il un _tag_ du genre 'irrégulier' ou 'exception' pour ce genre de question ?

Comment: I like this kind of question where I'm tempted to answer "Because it's like that" cause I know I will probably learn something :-) Note that not all "ai" are pronounced like "é". For exemple "vrai" is pronounced "vrè" (sorry I can't write or read phonetics), as (I think), chai, ...

Comment: The tags irrégulier or exception don't exist, and I don't have enough rep to create them :)

Comment: Duplicate of [Prononciation de « il faisait »](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/8249/prononciation-de-il-faisait)