# Pronunciation of "faisons" in French lyric diction

Tags: prononciation

In French lyric diction (poetry and art song), is the first vowel in "faisons" /œ/, as it is in everyday pronunciation?

Answer (score 1):

[fə.zɔ̃] is the usual pronunciation in France. *Faire* has a highly irregular pronunciation. The letters **ai** are pronounced /ə/ in:

- the *nous* form of the present indicative.
- all the forms in the  imperfect indicative.

In [this other answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/8315/358) @Gilles explains that this strange pronunciation might have its origin  in the fact that in the 17th century, the people in Paris wrongly pronounced the present participle [fə.zɑ̃] and this pronunciation spread to those other forms, and outside Paris.

I gather in France the vast majority of people will pronounce [fə] and not [fœ]. I could not say about other French speaking countries.

I wanted to refer you to an online pronunciation of the verb and hit upon [this one](http://www.audiofrench.com/verbs/faire_2.htm) which sounds entirely wrong to me. If you listen to the one on [Wiktionary](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/faisons) you will get it right.

Comment: Sorry to cause /œ/ vs. /ə/ confusion. When singing art song, we generally transcribe as /œ/, since the vowel is sustained when you sing. My question was really whether the /ə/ in "faisons" is perhaps a casual alternative to /ɛ/ and therefore not used in lyric diction (just as final "-e" is not pronounced in casual speech but gives an entire additional syllable when you sing, unless elided), or whether the first syllable is immutably /fə/ (and therefore sung /fœ/)?

Comment: Re your first audio link, I strongly suspect "Lauren" (who provided the audio) may not be Francophone - to my ears her pronunciation of "vous faites" also sounds distinctly British...

Comment: @Counterpoise In France pronouncing /ɛ/ would **definitely not** be not be an alternative. But artistic licence probably allows to move away from  the vernacular?

Comment: Great, that definitely decides it! As a non-Francophone I don't have the necessary instincts, that's what I needed to tap into. Just to intrigue you further, the singers' transcription will therefore be /fœ zõ/, though I'm not at all sure why we are taught that phoneme as /õ/ rather than /ɔ̃/...