# Prononciation de "fais" et de "faisons"

Tags: prononciation, voyelles

Je viens de me rendre compte que la prononciation de "ai" dans le mot "fais" est différente de celle dans le mot "faisons".

- [fais: /f**ɛ**/](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fais#Pronunciation)
- [faisons: /f**ə**.zɔ̃/](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/faisons#Pronunciation)

Jusqu'à présent je disais (mal, apparemment) /f**ɛ**.zɔ̃/.

J'ai rencontré un exemple similaire, avec "aime" (/ɛm/) et "aimons" (/e.mɔ̃/, /ɛ.mɔ̃/).

Est-ce qu'il y a un terme pour ce genre de changement de prononciation ? C'est peut-être un exemple de [voyelles ouvertes et fermées](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/pronunciation/open-and-closed-vowels-and-syllables/) ? Ou est-ce plutôt [quelque chose de spécifique à la conjugaison du mot "faire"](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/40093/2347) ?

Est-ce qu'il y a une règle qui indique où le changement de la prononciation est obligatoire (comme fais --> faisons) ou facultatif (comme aime --> aimons) ?

[Les corrections de ma grammaire et de mon orthographe sont les bienvenues.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C'est une anomalie spécifique au verbe faire et ses dérivés (contrefaire, parfaire, refaire, satisfaire, surfaire), mais qui a contaminé par homophonie *faisan* qui se prononce comme *faisant*.

Le *ai* du verbe faire se prononce /ɛ/ ou /e/ quand l'accent tonique se porte dessus (faire, je fais,...) mais se prononce /ə/ (ou ne se prononce pas du tout) dans les autres cas.

La logique orthographique aurait du conduire à écrire nous *fesons* au lieu de nous *faisons*, mais ce n'est malheureusement pas le cas. On peut noter que cette incohérence n'atteint pas le futur pour lequel on écrit bien *nous ferons* et pas *nous fairons*...

Les autres verbes en -aire ne changent pas de prononciation en fonction de l'accent tonique: *nous tairons* /nu.tɛ.ʁɔ̃/.