# Dès que je recevrai(s)

Tags: conjonctions, conditionnel

> Dès que je **recevrais** la version RC1 de Windows XP, je **ferais**
> quelques tests pour voir ce qu'il en est vraiment...

([lien](https://www.touslesdrivers.com/index.php?v_page=3&v_code=285))

Savez-vous pourquoi on utilise le conditionnel ici ? Je pense que c'est le futur qui convient, non ? Est-ce pour souligner une hypothèse, "Si je reçois cette version, dès que je la reçois..." ?

Aussi, cette phrase :

> Les choses iront mieux, dès que je **recevrais** ma lettre.

([lien](https://genius.com/Genius-traductions-francaises-heathers-the-musical-ensemble-beautiful-traduction-francaise-lyrics))

À mon avis, on devrait employer le futur dans cette phrase.

Comment: Je ne sais pas certain à 100 % pour ces phrases, mais j'aurais tendance à dire le même. Je trouve que les locuteurs natifs et sortis des programmes d'immersion (quit ont souvent une orthographe qui « lag behind » leur vocabulaire) confondent très souvent -ai/-ais en les écrivant.

Comment: @LukeSawczak Merci. Moi aussi, j'ai cette impression. Par exemple, j'écris rapidement en russe, sans trop me poser des questions et je suis sûre que je fais ce genre de fautes. C'est lorsque j'écris en français que je relis mes phrases.

Answer (score 6):

Le futur est bien le seul temps qui convient dans ces phrases et c'est certainement le sens qu'avaient en tête les auteurs des textes.

Ce sont donc soit des fautes d'inattention, soit des fautes tout court, dues à une mauvaise maîtrise de la conjugaison. Elles sont très courantes et il m'arrive souvent d'en faire de similaires, en particulier quand je ne me relis pas.

On peut facilement trouver des terminaisons encore plus fautives, ex. :

> *ok, je fer**ait** le montage avec silentbloc dès que je recevr**ait** les phares.*

> *...donc je ne connais pas les noms car je suis arriv**er** en retard, aprés le tour de table de présentation. un responsable sidecar a également ét**ais** élus...*

Une confusion probable entre futur et conditionnel dans [cette réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/49760/1109), encore que le futur n'y soit pas complètement exclu :

> *ils seront surement meilleurs que ceux que je pourr**ai** trouver*.

Je ne sais pas si ça joue beaucoup sur l'orthographe ici, mais les formes en *-ais*, *-ai*, *-ait*, *-é* et *-er* peuvent se prononcer de manière [identique ou non](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/95/pronunciation-of-ais-verbal-endings-prononciation-des-terminaisons-en-ais#:%7E:text=La%20prononciation%20du%20%C2%AB%20ai%20%C2%BB%20est,longue%20%E2%80%94%20genre%20%C2%AB%20%C3%A8%20%C2%BB.&text=En%20Fran%C3%A7ais%C2%B9%2C%20dans%20presque%20tous,exception%20%C3%A9tant%20%C3%A0%20la%20finale.), suivant l'accent, la région du locuteur, etc.

Comment: J'ai pensé à ceci, la question est aussi à @Fréfré : au Québec, on utilise le conditionnel pour "être plus polis" dans les phrases comme _Nous vous demander**ions** de signer ce formulaire._ Je sais qu'en France, on dirait _Nous vous demander**ons** de signer ce formulaire_ et que, pour les Français, utiliser le conditionnel ici serait une faute. La personne qui m'a écrit _dès que je recevrai**s**_ connait très bien le français, je relis toujours ses courriels afin d'apprendre. Peut-être que les Québécois emploient le conditionnel dans ce genre de phrases ? Je poserai cette question à qq.

Comment: @Oreste Je peux comprendre un conditionnel d'atténuation avec *nous vous demanderions de signer ce formulaire (si nous osions nous le permettre)* mais avec *dès que je recevrais*, on n'est pas pour moi dans le cas d'un verbe qui se prête à une atténuation. On n'exprime pas une demande ou un souhait.

Comment: Oui. Deux personnes d'ici m'ont aussi dit qu'il faut employer le futur. :)

Comment: @Oreste Le futur simple est correct, mais le futur antérieur est encore plus indiqué dans les deux exemples: *Dès que j'aurai reçu la version RC1...* et  *Les choses iront mieux dès que j'aurai reçu ma lettre*.

Comment: Je pense que cette terminaison fautive est classique, car les terminaison pour *Je* sont très souvent en *ais*, sauf au futur.

Comment: @XouDo C'est vrais ;-)

Comment: Je ne connais pas les particularités du français québécois. Mais je suppose que l’utilisation du conditionnel permet de formuler des demandes très polies. Nous ne sommes pas dans ce cas, ici. Ce n’est pas une demande. La présence de la conjonction de subordination “dès que” impose le futur (simple ou antérieur) car nous sommes dans le système du présent. 
Si le texte était au passé, on utiliserait le conditionnel pour sa valeur de futur dans le passé.

Answer (score 3):

Il suffit de passer ces phrases à la première ou deuxième personne du pluriel pour sentir qu'elles sont absolument fautives :

> Dès que vous recevriez la nouvelle version, vous feriez quelques tests.

Est inadmissible, c'est bien plutôt

> Dès que vous recevrez la nouvelle version, vous ferez quelques tests.

Comment: Merci. _Il suffit de passer ces phrases à la première ou deuxième personne du pluriel pour sentir qu'elles sont absolument fautives._ Oui... Cette astuce fonctionne surtout pour les francophones. Moi, si je n'avais pas lu des explications sur ce sujet, j'aurais bien pu écrire une phrase pareille.  // _Est inadmissible_ Que voulez-vous dire, svp ?

Comment: @Oreste je veux dire qu'on ne voit pas de situation dans laquelle on pourrait prononcer cette phrase; à moins peut-être d'imaginer des enfants jouant et parlant au conditionnel d'un jeu consistant à installer Windows XP :-)

Comment: Comme cela arrive pas hasard de temps à autre (mais rarement) de recevoir un exemplaire de Windows XP on est dans une considération hautement hypothétique :) Ou alors... "Imaginons que vous soyez téléporté au début des années 2000 : vous recevriez un CD de windows XP par la poste, vous feriez quelques tests"

Answer (score 2):

Seul le futur est possible dans ces phrases.

« Dès que je recevrai…, je ferai… »

« Les choses iront mieux, dès que je recevrai… »