# Jeux de mots (comme tumeur et tu meurs)

Tags: jeux-de-mots

Sans faute de ma part *tu meurs* et *tumeur* se prononcent identiquement. Je trouve ça hallucinant.

Tumeur et tu meurs ne sont pas très éloignés :-) !

Y a-t-il d'autres paires similaires ?

Comment: Tu ries, tuerie ;-) Il n'y a pas de calembours en grec ?

Comment: Ils on découvert le pote au noir !

Comment: @LPH Tu veux peut-être dire *ils ont découvert le poteau rose* ?

Comment: @jlliagre Du noir, rien que du noir… Je ne vois de rose nulle part ! (TLFi, Au fig. Situation difficile et dangereuse, dont on ne peut se dépêtrer. Synon. gêne, infortune, mélasse (fam.), misère, mouise (pop.), panade (pop.), pétrin (fam.), purée (pop.))

Comment: @LPH C'est un peu tiré par les cheveux, l'expression établie étant *découvrir le pot aux roses* et puis surtout, peu de gens prononcent *pot au noir* /potonwaʁ/ comme *pote au noir* /pɔtonwaʁ/, enfin, je pense mais je me trompe peut-être.

Comment: @jlliagre [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/pot_au_noir): pot au noir \pɔ.t‿o.nwaʁ\ masculin, invariable

Comment: @LPH Bof, si on écoute l'enregistrement marqué "Île-de-France", les deux O sont  pour moi identiques et fermés.

Comment: @jlliagre Pour moi aussi, deux o fermés, et la prononciation préférable de « pot » (dans « pot de bière » par exemple)  est aussi celle-là, à mon avis, mais apparemment on peut jouer sur les deux o. Cependant : découvrir le pot aux roses \de.ku.vʁiʁ lə po.t‿o ʁoz\ ([Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/d%C3%A9couvrir_le_pot_aux_roses))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Il doit en exister une infinité (ou pas loin) on appelle ça un calembour (https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calembour)

Quelques exemples (ils seront surement meilleurs que ceux que je pourrai trouver)
https://www.lalanguefrancaise.com/articles/24-calembours-les-plus-droles-de-la-langue-francaise

Comment: Je viens de penser à une chanson d'une saga MP3 qui est BOURREE de calembour/double sens et que j'aime bien, alors je partage :
https://soundcloud.com/user-255401077/jbx-reflet-dacide-wrandrall-demons-et-merveilles