# Est-ce que des mots adorerais et adorerai sont prononcés de la même façon ?

Tags: prononciation, conjugaison

Est-ce que des mots *adorerais* et *adorerai* sont prononcés de la même façon ?

Quand j'entend "adorerais" et "adorerai" sur des sites Internet, ils sont prononcés de la même façon. Pourquoi ?

Est-ce parce qu'ils sont générés par ordinateur ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pronunciation of -ai(s) verbal endings / Prononciation des terminaisons en -ai(s)](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/95/pronunciation-of-ais-verbal-endings-prononciation-des-terminaisons-en-ais)

Comment: En plus de la réponse acceptée, je conseillerais de lire aussi ces réponses plus conformes 
 aux réalités des prononciations rencontrées en France : https://french.stackexchange.com/a/6826/1109 et https://french.stackexchange.com/a/96/1109

Comment: Apparemment, il y a traditionnellement une différence, mais elle dépend des région (certains ne différencient pas é et è) et de l'habitude. Pour ma part j'avais appris (années 80) que les "AI" se prononcent toujours è, sauf dans fAIsant, fAIsons.

Comment: @XouDo Je ne crois pas qu'il y ait des régions ou le é et le è ne soient pas différenciés, en revanche, le choix d'utiliser l'un ou l'autre dépend du locuteur et de son accent.

Comment: le « é » et le « ai » ne sont pas très différents dans le sud-est («une fée» / «je fais» est différent, mais «j'ai mangé» est souvent prononcé «jé mangé»), en revanche « é » et « è » sont généralement différents («il a léché» / «il lèche»).

Comment: @PatrickT Pour ma part je fais bien la différence entre é et è mais je n'ai jamais prononcé (ni entendu dire) ces deux mots de façon différente (Région lyonnaise).

Answer (score 1):

Effectivement ces deux mots se prononcent de la même manière, on dit que le 's' est muet.

Comment: https://french.stackexchange.com/q/95/635

Comment: En théorie non, les prononciations de « ai » et de « ais » sont différentes. Détails [déjà donnés](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/100/358).

Comment: jamais entendu de différence!

Comment: Ce n'est pas le cas au Québec

Answer (score 1):

Ces deux mots ne se prononcent pas du tout de la même façon. Adorerais ( adorerè), Adorerai (adoreré).

Comment: Il y a une source ?   Voici le [tour] du site et quelques exemples https://french.stackexchange.com/q/95/1893 des bonnes réponses à la question (celle-ci est duplicata).